# .setBackgroundColor with Hex Color Codes AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
View targetView;
targetView = (View)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
```

this works but

```
targetView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

and also this didn't work

```
targetView.setBackgroundColor(Color.pasrsehexString("#FFFFFF"));
```

Error: Cannot resolve method'parseColor(java.lang.String)'

and  : Cannot resolve method'pasrsehexString(java.lang.String)'

Pleas can somebodey help me and by the way i'm using Android Studio.

Comment: Rebuild/Clean your project.

Comment: Make sure you've imported `android.graphics.Color` instead of `java.awt.Color`.

Comment: @Tom: Can you delete your comment and change it into an answer. Linus: There's no `pasrsehexString` method in `android.graphics.Color`. However, there is a [parseColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor%28java.lang.String%29) method which Tom has pointed out as the correct class to import for Android.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There are two main classes for color handling in Java/Android.

This first one is from "plain" Java and can be found in `java.awt.Color`.
This class supports converting a String into a color with the method [decode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29).
Example:

```
Color red = Color.decode("#FF0000");
```

The second class is for Android and can be found in `android.graphics.Color`.
The conversion can be done with the method [parseColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor%28java.lang.String%29).

```
int red = Color.parseColor("#FF0000");
```

So you should check which kind of `Color` class you've imported to your project. I recommend using the Android version of Color for your case. If you've done that the statement `targetView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));` should work.

Answer (score 8):

Define your color in the resource File color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="yourColor">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

and set Backgroundcolor

```
targetView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yourColor)
```

This may be helpful: [Color.xml](https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicMediaRouter/res/values/colors.html)

Comment: `setBackgroundColor` does not take a resource ID but a RGBA coded color. You have to resolve that manually.

Answer (score 5):

No need to parse string colors in your code.

If you want to hardcode color values in your code (and not use color resources as in FreshD's answer), you can use `int` literals for it. For example:

```
targetView.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
```

where the color is in ARGB.

Answer (score 4):

If you use **Kotlin** these ways can help you, you don't need import any extra Libs.

1- Direct by `0X` like this, (So-So)

```
dialogMiddleButton.setBackgroundColor(0XF00092)
```

2- Use `Color.parseColor` like this:**(The best one)**

```
dialogCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F06292"))
```